# Parent div scrollable, child div unscrollable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Is it possible to have a parent div scrollable (overflow:auto), but a child div unscrollable? No I can't use "position:fixed", because that fixes it to the viewport. **I need to fix the child div to the parent div.**

Code example:

```
#pagecontainer {
    overflow:auto;
    width:1000px;
    height:450px;
}
#pagecontainer>div{   /*each of the pages*/
    margin-top:50px;
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-right:50px;
    position:relative;
}
.unscrollable{
    position:absolute;
    width: 250px;
}
.scrollable{
    margin-left:300px;
    float:left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="pagecontainer">

    <div id="page1">

        <div class="unscrollable"> <!--UNSCROLLABLE-->
            <a href="#page1" class="link">Link 1</a>
            <p>
            <a href="#page2" class="link">Link 2</a>
            <p>
            <a href="#page3" class="link">Link 3</a>
            <p>
            <a href="#page4" class="link">Link 4</a>
            <p>
        </div>

        <div class="scrollable"> <!--SCROLLABLE-->
            content content content
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="page2">

        <div class="unscrollable"> <!--UNSCROLLABLE-->
            <a href="#page1" class="link">Link 1</a>
            <p>
            <a href="#page2" class="link">Link 2</a>
            <p>
            <a href="#page3" class="link">Link 3</a>
            <p>
            <a href="#page4" class="link">Link 4</a>
            <p>
        </div>

        <div class="scrollable"> <!--SCROLLABLE-->
            content content content
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I can't make only the child div `.scrollable` `overflow:auto` (that will indeed fix `.unscrollable`), because then the scrollbar will have a 50px gap due to the margin of 50px, and it will scroll only relative to .scrollable. I need the scrollbar to be on `#pagecontainer`, or `#page1`/`#page2` is fine as well.

Also I cannot put `.unscrollable` outside `#pageX`. I need the code to be organized, `.unscrollable` is a section of each page. If I put `.unscrollable` outside `#pageX`, then I need to create an ID for unscrollable for each page, ie `#unscrollable1` `#unscrollable2`, then call (`#page1`,`#unscrollable1`).fadeIn() when I want to show that page, instead of simply (`#page1`).fadeIn(). That will get unbelievably messy. **So bottom line is the structure of the divs cannot be changed**.

What I need is some javascript/jQuery function that makes `.unscrollable` fixed to `#pagecontainer` or `#page1`/`#page2` overriding any css, something like (`.unscrollable`).fixTo(`#pagecontainer`) if that exists.

Comment: Offtopic, but in the future, choose your tags more wisely.  The tags you chose were pretty useless or flat-out wrong.  Without good tags, the relevant tech experts will not see your question.  I replaced your tags with my best guess at what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsfiddle showing one possible solution.
http://jsfiddle.net/SF7nr/

I removed the floating for the scrollable and set a `max-height` and an `overflow: auto;` to activate the scrolling.

For layout reasons I also set an min-height for the page itself.
Check it out.

Answer (score -1):

To fix the child to the parent `div`, try using `position: relative` on the parent `div` and `position: fixed` on the child `div`.

Then all positioning you do with the child `div` (`top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right`) will be relative to the parent `div`.

Comment: Uh..no it won't. Position:fixed always fixes it to viewport no matter what the css settings are. o.O